# Most data within rectangle of given area

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to find the most amount of data within a 2D array of values given a maximum rectangle area.

Let's say for this image, the best rectangle would look something like this:
"[best-rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2dQg.png)". Where the most amount of data is fitting within the rectangle but the rectangle cannot exceed a certain area.

[original-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctEem.png)

Comment: [Top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJGNX.png) seems to be more 'data', IIUC.

Comment: Yes thats true. The current red rectangle is more of an example to illustrate the idea.

Comment: @veech Is the a binary black & white image?

Comment: It's an 8-bit grey scale image where the empty values are 0. I could also use `cv2.threshold` to convert it into a binary black and white image if needed.

Comment: "integral image". makes sums easy to compute. then find the position having the largest sum, given your fixed size of rectangle. -- provide the data without scribbles on it if you want a demonstration. -- if however you want to vary the size of the rectangle too, that's getting more complicated.

Comment: Added original image without thresholding to original post